# How to create Stacked ColumnCharts with different colors in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, charts, stacked

I am trying to create a stacked column chart that will show three different values on a column with different colors. Please let me know how to achieve that.

Thanks,
AM

Answer (score 0):

I answered a similar question [here](http://forums.adobe.com/message/3309235#3309235). And you may also be interested in a relevent follow up [here](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/760576).

To set the colors, you just need to set the stroke and fill properties on the series.